# How can i put an object in object in golang

Tags: go

What i am trying to do is to load an whole object coming from my database into an object.

```
type RatingPK struct {
    ratingsPK Rating
}

func (r *RatingPK) Init(rg Rating) {
    r.ratingsPK = rg
}    

func searchUserRatings(id string)(ratings []Rating)  {

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE userId = ?", id)

    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    for rows.Next() {

        rate := Rating{}

        err = rows.Scan(&rate.MovieId, &rate.UserId, &rate.RatingId, &rate.Rating, &rate.Timestamp)

        if err != nil {
            return
        }

        r := RatingPK{}
        r.Init(rate)
        ratings = append(ratings, r)
    }

    defer rows.Close()

    return
}
```

this code gives me this result:

```
   [{
    "rating_id": 593,
    "userId": 2,
    "movieId": 93,
    "rating": 3,
    "timestamp": "0000-00-00"
  },
  {
    "rating_id": 616,
    "userId": 2,
    "movieId": 94,
    "rating": 3,
    "timestamp": "0000-00-00"
  }]
```

Now what i want to do is to get each object of the array and put in to another object and the desired result will be this:

```
[{"ratingsPK": {
    "rating_id": 593,
    "userId": 2,
    "movieId": 93,
    "rating": 3,
    "timestamp": "0000-00-00"
  }},
  {"ratingsPK": {
    "rating_id": 616,
    "userId": 2,
    "movieId": 94,
    "rating": 3,
    "timestamp": "0000-00-00"
  }}]
```

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may loop and do as follows

```
type RatingPK struct {
    ratingsPK Rating
}

func (r *RatingPK) Init(rg Rating) {
    r.ratingsPK = rg
}

func searchUserRatings(id string) (ratings []RatingPK) {

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE userId = ?", id)

    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    var myarray []string

    for rows.Next() {
        rate := Rating{}
        err = rows.Scan(&rate.MovieId, &rate.UserId, &rate.RatingId, &rate.Rating, &rate.Timestamp)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        r := RatingPK{}
        r.Init(rate)
        ratings = append(ratings, r)
    }

    defer rows.Close()
    return
}
```

Comment: In my func SearchUserRatings what should i replace? Thanks

Comment: Here the function i proposed is in sich a way that you may give result of your search fuction as input to this. I'll update your function

Comment: what is the variable result in the init method?

Comment: Init initializes itself does not return anything. It is used as `ratingsPK` is not an exported field other ways you can straigt forward put it

Comment: in the append method the r variable it gives me error..can not use r (type ratingPK) as type Rating..

Comment: i have update my code, you can check it..but it doesnt work..i get error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134868/discussion-between-sarathsp-and-codel).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short example that will help you understand how to use nested structs ;)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type nameType struct {
    firstName string
    lastName string
}

type student struct {
    name nameType
    age int
}

func main() {
    bob := student{nameType{"bob", "dope"}, 18}

    fmt.Println(bob.name.firstName)
}
```

You can test it up here ;)

https://play.golang.org/p/ft9PGrlrrx